# Making a movie clip come from other side when leaving frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So im trying to make an easy script, which will hold a video...

And i will be able to drag the video around as i want, but the catch is... when it leaves borders of the frame, i want it to continue playing on the other side, even if its only half of the video or less...

I know how to transport it, to the other side, but not the half of it or less..

```
function everyFrame(event:Event):void {
    if (movie.x + 100 < 1)
        movie.x = 400;
}
```

Here is an image of the effect that im trying to achieve... https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H6Yi.png
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more code, I would say you need to set clipAndEnableScrolling.

```
clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
```

Try adding that to the group (Group, HGroup, or VGroup) that you have your video in.

Edit based on me understanding now...:

When the right edge of your movie touches the right edge of the screen, you will need to create a second movie and add it to the stage at a determined x of the first movie and y of first movie. I would say something like this...

```
onMoveOfFirstMovie():void
{
    if(firstMovie.x + firstMovie.width > movieContainer.width)
    {
        if(secondMovie doesnt exist)
        {
            //create second movie if it isnt already on stage and set it's play position to the play position of first movie
        }

        secondMovie.y = firstMovie.y;
        secondMovie.x = firstMovie.x + firstMovie.width - movieContainer.width;
    }
}
```

Very rough code but it should be about right.

Comment: No, that's not it.. i know how to move the video around, i just dont know how to make the video appear on the other side while its still on the side that i am pushing it againts...

Comment: Ahhhh... I see what your saying. I misinterpreted what your picture was doing... Updating answer now.

Comment: You can also do it something like this: http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2012/06/endless-scrolling-bathroom.html. That way, you only have to have one.